# How can a web page be redirected to a data: uri from http://?

Tags: debugging, hyperlink, safari, bookmarklet, data-uri

I would like to load a webpage with limited contact to a server. I have a cross-application link but safari just will not open the data: uri. Is there anyway to begin that with http://? What about javascript in a url, `http://javascript:window.location="data:"?` I do not want to have to contact a server (offline stuff).

If not, could I use a simple php page to redirect it?
Ex:

`http://someserver/index.php?input="data:text/html;charset=UTF-8,htmlhere"`

and in the php script:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=< ?php echo($GET_['input']); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `meta` tag to redirect with the data URI as the `url` property value:

```
<html>
<!--Using meta redirect--> 
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url= data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQAQMAAAAlPW0iAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAAM0lEQVR4nGP4/5/h/1+G/58ZDrAz3D/McH8yw83NDDeNGe4Ug9C9zwz3gVLMDA/A6P9/AFGGFyjOXZtQAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
>
</html>
```

**References**

- [OWASP Fuzzing Code Database: XSS Discovery Statement](https://owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Fuzzing_Code_Database#XSS_Discovery_Statements)